# How do I get the logo path?

Tags: theming, 8

I am creating custom theme for Drupal 8. I am uploading the logo from theme setting, but I am not able to print the path of that logo. What I am doing to print the full path of logo is using `{{ logo }}`, but it is not working.

In Drupal 7 we can get the full path of logo with the following code.

```
 <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
```

What is the equivalent for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 14):

The class implementing the block showing the theme logo, in [`SystemBrandingBlock::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21SystemBrandingBlock.php/function/SystemBrandingBlock%3A%3Abuild/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```
  $build['site_logo'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#uri' => theme_get_setting('logo.url'),
    '#alt' => $this->t('Home'),
    '#access' => $this->configuration['use_site_logo'],
  );
```

So, for the path of the logo, you can simply use `theme_get_setting('logo.url')`, which returns `"/core/themes/bartik/logo.svg"`, in my test site.

If you want a relative URL for the logo file, for example because you want to use it for the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag, you can do as [`template_preprocess_image()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_image/8.2.x) does.

```
$relative_url = file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url(theme_get_setting('logo.url')));
```

For an absolute URL, you can use the following code.

```
$absolute_url = file_create_url(theme_get_setting('logo.url'));
```

That code needs to go in a preprocess function, where it initializes a variable. For example, if I wanted the relative URL of the logo file in html.html.twig, I would use the following code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['relative_logo_url'] = file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url(theme_get_setting('logo.url')));
}
```

And in the template, you would just use `{{ relative_logo_url }}` to get it.

Comment: The example of the absolute path does nothing, what would be the difference with the relative

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, [the site logo was moved in a block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2544012).

In block layout, you place a branding block in a region, which you then can configure to contain the logo, the site name and/or the slogan. You can place multiple branding blocks to use site branding elements in different regions.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've placed the "Site branding" block to the appropriate region but the logo image is showing broken. When I check the source code it is showing this <img src="http://example.com/themes/theme_name/logo.svg" alt="Home">
but I added the .jpg image with different name from theme setting but every time it is showing logo image name logo.svg